# How do I enable a cheat file in RetroArch?

Tags: emulation, cheats, retroarch

I'm using the core **FCEUX** ("FCEUmm") in **[RetroArch](https://buildbot.libretro.com/stable/1.3.6/windows/)** (x64) in Windows 10 to play NES games.

The problem I have is when I try to load a **[cheat file](https://github.com/libretro/libretro-database/tree/master/cht/Nintendo%20Entertainment%20System/Game%20Genie)**, the application breaks. You all know that RetroArch has the most annoying user interface you could find for an emulator and not well officially documented at all, so I'm not sure how to properly load a cheat, I tried to follow the steps shown in **[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uvh5Sr7LlSc)**, however when I press F1 key to show the RetroArch's menu I don't have the same options.

The thing is, firstly I load a NEs game, I press the F1 key to open the menu, then I go to this section:

[image]

Then I choose the desired cheat file:

[image]

At this point, the menu just closes, the RetroArch's UI does not informs me about whether the cheat file was loaded right or what the hell happened to close the menu...

Well, supposing that the cheat file is loaded ok at this point, then I press F1 key again to search for the cheat codes that I want to enable, and here at this point RetroArch just crashes itself, the application closes completely.

I tested several amount of NES games trying to do these steps with different cheat files, always happens the same, this only could be a bug, or not?.